# ssh-agent with passwords without spawning too many processes

Tags: linux, ssh

I use ssh-agent with password-protected keys on Linux. Every time I log into a certain machine, I do this:

```
eval `ssh-agent` && ssh-add
```

This works well enough, but every time I log in and do this, I create another ssh-agent. Once in a while, I will do a `killall ssh-agent` to reap them. Is there a simple way to reuse the same ssh-agent process across different sessions?

Comment: See also this excellent answer: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/90869/92102

Answer (score 5, accepted):

have a look at Keychain. It was written b people in a similar situation to yourself.
[Keychain](http://www.gentoo.org/proj/en/keychain/)

Answer (score 3):

How much control do you have over this machine? One answer would be to run ssh-agent as a daemon process. Other options are explained on [this web page](http://mah.everybody.org/docs/ssh), basically testing to see if the agent is around and then running it if it's not.

To reproduce one of the ideas here:

```
SSH_ENV="$HOME/.ssh/environment"

function start_agent {
     echo "Initialising new SSH agent..."
     /usr/bin/ssh-agent | sed 's/^echo/#echo/' > "${SSH_ENV}"
     echo succeeded
     chmod 600 "${SSH_ENV}"
     . "${SSH_ENV}" > /dev/null
     /usr/bin/ssh-add;
}

# Source SSH settings, if applicable

if [ -f "${SSH_ENV}" ]; then
     . "${SSH_ENV}" > /dev/null
     #ps ${SSH_AGENT_PID} doesn’t work under cywgin
     ps -ef | grep ${SSH_AGENT_PID} | grep ssh-agent$ > /dev/null || {
         start_agent;
     }
else
     start_agent;
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
ssh-agent $SHELL
```

This will cause ssh-agent to exit when the shell exits. They still won't be shared across sessions, but at least they will go away when you do.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which shell you use, you can set different profiles for login shells and mere regular new shells.  In general you want to start ssh-agent for login shells, but not for every subshell.  In bash these files would be `.bashrc` and `.bash_login`, for example.

Most desktop linuxes these days run ssh-agent for you.  You just add your key with ssh-add, and then forward the keys over to remote ssh sessions by running

```
ssh -A
```